# Dependence Injection refactor

Tags: dependency-injection

I'm thinkig about "How refactor class when object are injecting by constructor, method or DI container"

Simple example of injectiong by constructor.

```
<?php
class Person {
    private $db;
    function constructor($db) {
        $this->db = $db;  
    }
}
```

This is realy nice but, let's image that class Person is used at other class like Report, Photos, Searcher etc. So each of that class need $db inject by construction or method even if they do not need db connection.

Next class Person needs cache object.

```
<?php
class Person {
    private $db;
    function constructor($db, $cache) {
        $this->db = $db;  
        $this->cache = $cache;  
    }
}
```

Now we need to update Report, Photos, Searcher. If project is big, it's not easy task.

So think that maybe better solution would be inject entire Dependence Injection Container (service location)

```
<?php
class Person {
    private $db;
    function constructor($di) {
        $this->db = $di->get('db');  
        $this->cache = $di->get('cache');  
    }
}
```

It seems that resolve one part of my problem with refactor. But this solution is almost like global variable. It's example of antipattern.

Please let know about good practices with this.